# How to stop panels from refreshing when navigating from edit page to dashboard page in grafana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana

I am using grafana version `v9.3.2`.

We are pulling some data from amazon athena datasources and queries are quite large. We do not want these queries to be running automatically since there is cost associated with each time we query database. For this we have disabled the `Refresh live dashboards` option inside the dashboard settings. We have also enabled `Hide time picker` option from same set of settings. But still the dashboard refreshes when we navigate from edit panel screen to dashboard page.

Is there a way this can be disabled? I want the dashboard to refresh panels only when we ask it to and not automatically.

Comment: Same issue here, did you solve it?